# How do I transfer my iPhone and iTunes application to another computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes, migration

I have my iPhone and iTunes set up on a specific computer but want to transfer this to another computer.

Do I just install iTunes on the new computer and just sync my iPhone etc.. or is there anything special I have to do ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want to do:

If you have an iPod (not iPhone or iPod Touch), you can follow **Apple's official method** :

[iPod 101: Backing Up Your Library](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA38534?viewlocale=en_US)

Otherwise you might want to read about the various **other methods** to copy your iTunes library to another computer (may it be a Mac or otherwise):

[How to Transfer iTunes Library to Another Computer](http://ipod.about.com/od/howtos/a/transfer_itunes.htm)

This is the method I used successfully which does not require any other third party software:

[How to Transfer Your iTunes Library to a New Computer in Five Minutes](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/789495/how_to_transfer_your_itunes_library.html)

On a related matter, should your iTunes library ever get destroyed (disk failure), stolen (together with your laptop) or simply corrupted; there still hope if all your music is on your iPod or iPhone. Senuti is a (non-free) software that can recover music from an iPod or iPhone when the original iTunes library it was synced from is no longer available for the reasons stated earlier.
[How to Use Senuti](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Senuti)

If your *entire library* is already synced your Pod, you can use Senuti to copy all the music on the device to the target computer of your choice:

[Senuti - Copy music from iPod to Mac](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060809085501683)

Senuti is available http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/

The trial version can only recover/copy up to 800 songs.

Comment: I used the third method a few months ago and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can using [iTools](http://itools.hk/en_index.htm)
it has many funtion to backup and copy data from Iphone, access to many folder in iphone and with visually interface, it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a new laptop the other day and found the best solution was to install [myTuneSync](http://www.socketheadstudios.com/mytunesync/) on each computer, then use it to synchronize the two libraries.  This avoids any problems with paths, Windows/Mac conversion, etc.

After doing that, you'll need to sync the iPhone with the new computer, which will dissociate it from the original computer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What would happen if I just installed ITunes only on the new PC and then did a sync ? - Would it copy all the music/podcasts etc.. from the iphone back onto the new PC ?

Comment: The iPhone sync is a one way sync, and therefore it will be bound to the first machine you synced on. The direct answer is no.