# How to backup iPhone to a new computer without losing any data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup

I am afraid of losing any data (it happened to me on in the past when syncing a smartphone to  Windows - lost all contacts)

What is the safest way of doing this on a Windows PC?  (The iPhone is also jailbroken - does it make any difference?)

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/29138/lost-info-by-syncing-iphone-to-new-computer

Answer (score 1):

Tell iTunes to sync it as an existing phone, and it shouldn't remove anything. Or, migrate the iTunes library to the new machine, and then sync the phone.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this on Windows, only on Macs.

Comment: It is the same on Windows as well

Answer (score 0):

From memory if the phone is jailbroken, then it will backup / sync to any computer. However you can plug it in and see - itunes wont go and delete anything without your permission :)

Comment: Sorry to tell you @JT.WK but this is most certainly NOT true: ***itunes wont go and delete anything without your permission***
I have been burned many times!