# Sync iPhone 4 to a new computer

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I transfer my iPhone and iTunes application to another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/661/how-do-i-transfer-my-iphone-and-itunes-application-to-another-computer)
>   [Transfer music from iPhone to the computer](https://superuser.com/questions/25446/transfer-music-from-iphone-to-the-computer)

i have a emergent problem for my iphone 4.
My old computer crashed. I now need to sync my iphone to a new computer. How can I do this when the iphone is only made to sync to one computer? help please!

Comment: one computer at a time. It'll lose sync with the crashed computer, but that's not an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I transfer my iPhone and iTunes application to another computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/661/how-do-i-transfer-my-iphone-and-itunes-application-to-another-computer) also see [Lost info by syncing iPhone to new computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/29138/lost-info-by-syncing-iphone-to-new-computer)

Answer (score 1):

Ehm... Install [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) and connect your phone?